# Cannot place add to cart woocommerce button inside a custom div class in product categories

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I have ratings and add to cart button next to each other. But I need to place add to cart button in the parent of ratings div class. **In order to align the button to the right using flex css**. Because I have

[image]

I did the following with no result

```
echo '<div class ="mywrapper">'. woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() . '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' );
echo '</div></div>';

echo '<div class ="mywrapper">'. <? php echo woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() ?> . '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' );
echo '</div></div>';
```

The add to cart always is outside class "mywrapper"

[image]

While I need to have the following

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I did it by doing the following

```
echo '<div class ="mywrapper">'. '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' );
echo '</div>';
echo woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); 
echo '</div>';
```

instead of one echo